# Show that $p \leq q \iff pq = qp = p.$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, projection

> Let $p,q$ be two projections in a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A.$ Then show that $$p \leq q \iff pq = qp = p.$$

By projection we usually mean those elements in a $C^{\ast}$-algebra which are self-adjoint and idempotent. With this definition in mind how do I approach the problem? Could anyone give me some hints?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try thinking of the case that $A = B(H)$; the space of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space. Projections in $B(H)$ correspond to orthogonal projections onto a closed subspace and if $P,Q \in B(H)$ are projections then $P \le Q$ means $Ran(P) \subseteq Ran(Q)$.

Comment: For such projections $P, Q \in B(H)$ we have $\left \langle Qx, x \right \rangle = \|x\|^2,$ for all $x \in \text {Ran} (P).$ This implies that $Q\ \lvert_{\text {Ran} (P)} = P\ \lvert_{\text {Ran} (P)}.$ Therefore we have  $$\text {Ran} (P) = \text {Ran} \left (P\ \lvert_{\text {Ran} (P)} \right ) = \text {Ran} \left (Q\ \lvert_{\text {Ran} (P)} \right ) \subseteq \text {Ran} \left (Q \right ).$$ What should I do now @Austin Shiner?

Comment: @Austin Shiner$:$ That means here $QP = P.$ Taking adjoints in both the sides we have $PQ = P.$ Now how to tackle this for the general case?

Comment: For the general case use the Gelfand-Naimark theorem and choose a Hilbert space $H$ and $\ast$-isomorphism $\Gamma$ from $A$ onto a $\ast$-subalgebra of $B(H)$. Note that $\Gamma$ preserves $\le$ (why?), and now you are back in the special case that you just showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(note that assuming $A$ unital changes nothing, and it simplifies arguments)*

If $pq=qp=p$, then
$$
p=qp=qpq\leq q1q=q^2=q. 
$$
Conversely, suppose that $p\leq q$. Then
$$
0\leq (1-q)p(1-q)\leq(1-q)q(1-q)=0. 
$$
So $$(1-q)p(1-q)=0.$$ This we can write as
$$
0=(1-q)p(1-q)=(1-q)p^*p(1-q)=[p(1-q)]^*p(1-q). 
$$
Thus (thank God for the C$^*$-identity!)
$$
0=p(1-q). 
$$
That is, $p=pq$. Taking adjoints, $p=qp$.